# Book featuring a computer that used pantropy to colonize worlds, and a girl with a socket in her head

Tags: story-identification, books, space-colonization

I read a book about 20 years ago about a computer that used [pantropy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pantropy) to colonize worlds with modified humans.  I think that the purpose was to ensure that humanity would not go extinct.  What I remember is that the one of the characters in the story was a girl that had a socket in her head and had to be pregnant in order to function.

The characters were on a quest to find the control room of the computer so that they could bring it back under control.  When they did find the computer, the girl directly interfaced with the computer via the socket in her head.

Comment: This description was a wild ride for someone whose native tongue is not English. I was trying so hard to visualize someone with a sock (material, woolen sock) in her head, thinking how deranged someone must have been to put it there. And how would the "interfacing" work?? Then I remembered that I work in IT and everything was normal again.

Comment: Note that proposed duplicate target is the hub for a large number of other closed questions about the series (even though the question itself is about just one book in it).

Comment: @DavidGlaser, FYI -- the nomination to close this as a duplicate is not a mark against your question; it's just site policy to do this for story ID questions so that all questions about a particular story are linked.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

This is *[Rings of the Master](https://www.goodreads.com/series/41810-rings-of-the-master)* by Jack Chalker, a series of four books; "Lords of the Middle Dark", "Pirates of the Thunder", "Warriors of the Storm", and "Masks of the Martyrs". Published 1986-1988

Five golden rings are the key humanity needs to reclaim control of the Master Computer System. They are scattered across space on worlds settled by peoples that were once human.

Comment: Thank you.  Looks like the series I sought.